# Error:The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have this code in my project:

```
MCvFont font = new MCvFont(FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, 0.2d, 0.2d);
```

When program runs, It gives an exception:

> The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.

So please help me with on this issue.

Comment: You need to look at the *complete* exception - there'll be an inner exception which explains what went wrong. We're unlikely to be able to help you without that.

Answer (score 0):

Usually these kind of "Emgu.CV.CvInvoke" exception will throw if there are some problems with your Emgucv Dll's.

Check these following thing's:

1. Open Your Project & Verify whether all the Project-> Reference's are made correctly.e.g Emgu.CV.UI.dll,Emgu.CV.dll,Emgu.CV.dll etc..
2. Check the Copy to Local Check box is ticked or not.
3. If your OS is 32-Bit then make sure you are linking only 32-Bit Dll's. If you are working with 64-Bit OS then copy relevant 64-Bit Dll's.
4. Copy the opencv_xxx.dll's from your opencv directory to your Bin Dir.
5. Finally Check all the dll's are present in the Bin directory or not.

Now compile & run the program.